# getting differences values between two dataset of csv files

Tags: python, csv, mean

I have two dataset of weather parameters values (temperature , pressure , humidity ,...etc) versus height above sea level .Each dataset has an equal huge number of csv files   . I want to calculate difference value of each parameter between every two similar csv files in same location and time from these two dataset in python . How can I do it ?

Comment: If possible, try to share a snippet of your data

Comment: How can I upload a file here?